# Using Gradle to download dependencies to folder but only war-file

Tags: gradle

I need to download my applications-packages from my nexus, currently I am trying to achieve this with gradle. Its working quite well but it downloads too much, I just want to download the war-package of the given artifact.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    maven {
        url "${nexusUrl}/nexus/content/groups/public/"
    }   
}

dependencies {   
compile group:"com.foobar", name:"ash-war", version:"4.2.2-SNAPSHOT"   
}

task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
from configurations.compile
into 'gradle_apps'
}
```

As you can see the dependend jars of my artefact has been downloaded too, but I want only to download the war file of my artefact.

[image]

Comment: Use transitive: false on your compile dependency. Google how to use it.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes it can be really easy adding this changed it like I want configurations.all{
    transitive = false
}

Comment: You can use it on single dependency as well if you want.